# Predictive Power of Negative Binomial Regression

Tags: predictive-models, negative-binomial-distribution

I am interested in comparing the predictive power of two independent variables to predict Y. 
I run two negative binomial regression; let's say 
$Y = b_0 +b_1X_1 / Y= b_0 + b_2x_2$

Since there is multicollinearity between $x_1$ and $x_2$, I cannot combine them within a single model, and compare their coefficients. I used AIC/BIC and the results;

$Y = b_0 +b_1x_1 $ (Pseudo $R^2$ = 0.1546 ; AIC= 781,4775 ; BIC = 787,33)
$Y= b_0 + b_2x_2 $(Pseudo $R^2$ = 0.1669; AIC = 770, 2174 ; BIC = 776.0711)

Is it sufficient to say that model 2 predicts better Y than model 1?